# Predicate logic and validity

Tags: predicate-logic

I have the following task:

"Show that Pa V Pb -> Ex Px is valid" where E stands for the existential quantifier.

I have done the following:
- Let M denote a model with domain D, and assume that M |= Pa V Pb
- It suffices then to show that M |= Ex Px
- Let s be an element in D, arbitrarily chosen
- By assumption, we know that M |= Ps (since we consider disjunction, it suffices to only include one, from Pa V Pb)
- Thus, it is the case that M |= Ex Ps
- Since s was arbitrarily chosen, it will be so that M |= Ex Px, that Ex Px is true in M.

Is this the right way to prove validity?

Comment: From what I remember, there is the method of truth trees.

Comment: Maybe this would also work: from $PaV Pb$ one must be true, say $Pa$. Then I think you can conclude from $Pa$, that $Ex Px$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks okay at a glance, but I could be wrong. Using tableux is much more succinct: you assume $Pa\vee Pb$ but also $\neg\exists xPx$ to get

[image: Tab],

which ends in contradictions. The tableau of the negation of your formula is closed. Hence it is valid.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into that.

Comment: You're welcome. A great place to start is S.G.Simpson's lecture notes on Mathematical Logic.